# Error when storing names of subdirectories as nodes in list

Tags: c++, list, directory

I open a directory that has multiple subdirectories with names of countries. What i want is to make a list and store the paths of these directories in the nodes. The issue comes up when i print the list and in the destructor. I don't seem to get what's wrong since i've used these functions multiple times before with no issue coming up.

The directory looks something like this:

```
input_dir
   >Tanzania
   >Honduras
   >iTaiwan
   >Albania
   >Qatar
   >Grenada
   >Thailand
   >Croatia
   >Guatemala
   >Uruguay
```

Here's all the code:
My main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int num_elements; //command line arguments
  char* input_dir_path;

  num_elements = stoi(argv[1]);
  strcpy(input_dir_path, argv[2]);

  Countries all_countries;
  fetch_countries(num_elements,all_countries,input_dir_path);

  all_countries.print();

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the function where i open the directory and store the paths on the list:

```
void fetch_countries( int num_monitors,  Countries& all_countries, char* input_dir_path)
{
  DIR * input_dir = opendir(input_dir_path); // open the path

  if(input_dir == NULL){
    cout<< "Error opening directory" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  char buffer[257];
  struct dirent *entry;  // for the directory entries
  
  while ((entry = readdir(input_dir)) != NULL)
  {
    char *f_name = entry->d_name;
    if (entry->d_type != DT_DIR || !strcmp(f_name, ".") || !strcmp(f_name, ".."))  // Ignore . and .. dirs
      continue;
    // buffer contains instance: input_dir/Uruguay
    sprintf(buffer, "%s/%s", input_dir_path, f_name);
    all_countries.Insertion(buffer);  // storing all of the countries on a list
  }
  closedir(input_dir);
}
```

And finally the list functions:

```
class CountryNode
{
public:
    string country;
    CountryNode* next;
    CountryNode(const string country);
    ~CountryNode();
};

class Countries
{
public:
    CountryNode* head;
    CountryNode* tail;
    Countries();
    ~Countries();
    void Insertion(const string country);
    void print();
};

void Countries::Insertion(const string country)
{
  CountryNode* newnode = new CountryNode(country);

  //the list is empty
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    head = newnode;
    tail = newnode;
    return;
  }
  tail->next = newnode;
  tail = newnode;
}

Countries::Countries()
{
  head = NULL;
  tail = NULL;
}

void Countries::print()
{ // now we print the nodes
  CountryNode* current;
  current=head;
  while (current != NULL)
  {
    cout << current->country << endl;
    if (current->next != NULL)
      cout << "->";
    current = current->next;
  }
  cout << endl;
}

Countries::~Countries()
{
  CountryNode* current = head;
  CountryNode* next;

  while (current != NULL)
  {
    next = current->next;
    delete current;
    current = next;
  }
  
  head = NULL;
  tail = NULL;
}

CountryNode::CountryNode(const string country)
:country(country)
{}

CountryNode::~CountryNode() {}
```

Finally the error i get:

```
input_dir/Tanzania
->input_dir/Honduras
->input_dir/Taiwan
->input_dir/Albania
->input_dir/Qatar
->input_dir/Grenada
->input_dir/Thailand
->input_dir/Croatia
->input_dir/Guatemala
->input_dir/Uruguay
==16098== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16098==    at 0x10BA29: Countries::print() (in /home/...)
==16098==    by 0x10A8F4: main (in /home/...)
==16098== 
==16098== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16098==    at 0x10B9F4: Countries::print() (in /home/...)
==16098==    by 0x10A8F4: main (in /home/...)
==16098== 

==16098== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==16098==    at 0x10BA87: Countries::~Countries() (in /home/...)
==16098==    by 0x10A980: main (in /home/....)
==16098== 
==16098== 
==16098== HEAP SUMMARY:
==16098==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==16098==   total heap usage: 533 allocs, 533 frees, 153,121 bytes allocated
==16098== 
==16098== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==16098== 
==16098== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==16098== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==16098== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Is there something i'm not seeing? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: to save someone's time from commenting i'm not going to use stl

Comment: _" i'm not going to use stl "_ Any resilient reasoning why not? If yes [edit] your question to add that information please.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

Comment: You never set `newNode->next` in `Insertion()`

Comment: @Barmar you mean set it to NULL?

Comment: You are already using the standard library so what's stopping you from going all-in?

Comment: I wouldn't use STL either. It's so 1990s.  The C++ Standard Library, on the other hand...

Comment: @user4581301 already using that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set `newnode->next` to `NULL`. So when you loop through the list of nodes, you run into an unitialized pointer when you get to the last node.

You can change the `CountryNode` constructor to initialize it to this default.

```
CountryNode::CountryNode(const string country)
    :country(country), next(NULL)
{}
```

Comment: Yup that was the issue... Thank you so much have a great day! :)